# Heroku scheduler unreliable and runs randomly instead of scheduled time

Tags: heroku

I am trying to deploy a basic python script, which needs to be run at a gives schedule, collect data and write to a file.
When i schedule to run this every hour, the Heroku scheduler is running it every 15-20 minutes once.
I am new to Heroku and just trying to run a basic python scrapping script as a worker process using scheduler. Is this something doable in Heroku? I am familiar with cron jobs in linux which could be used to do something similar, but because of our project preference had to go with Heroku.
Appreciate your inputs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are other cloud schedulers out there which are more reliable and more production-grade than Heroku Scheduler. [Cron To Go](https://crontogo.com/) is one such scheduler that is also an Heroku add-on (full disclosure, I work for the company that created it). It allows you to use cron expressions to run your code on Heroku one-off dynos. You can also get email and webhook notifications when failures occur. Note that if Heroku is having issues with starting dynos or with its APIs, your jobs may not be executing in a timely manner - but usually, when there's an incident in Heroku, you will have other worries too :)